# Create the UNIX Echo class in Java

Tags: java, string, arguments, echo

I am very very new to java and I'm trying to create the echo class found in UNIX in java. 
Basically, if I type in:

```
Echo 'i love you'
```

the command line prints

```
i love you
```

I have that part figured out, however, I can't seem to figure out the command line option `-n` which gets rid of the newline

I edited by code after reading the comment. However, it is still not doing what I hoped.
[My new code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycjpu.png)

[The output of my new code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJfar.png)
As you can see, even after I enter the `-n`, the word is still on a newline

Comment: System.out.println will always print a new line! Try System.out.print

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into your question. Don't worry about formatting, someone will do it for you

Comment: Don't post image of your code but your code itself. More info: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1393766

Comment: Thank you @bdavies6086, it worked perfectly!

Comment: @Elina0524 Brilliant! I shall post it as an answer so you can close this one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, as seen in the comments is to use System.out.print as opposed to System.out.println

Answer (score 2):

In Java the array starts with `0`. So the code should look like this>

```
if (args[0].equals("-n")
```

By the way, you should compare two strings with `string.equals(..)` method, not with the double equation operator.

Comment: @cricket_007 no, not in Java, so `args[0]` doesn't contain `java` or `javaw` but simply first argument used after `java Class args`.

Comment: wouldn't args[0] be Echo?
Because if I type in : java Echo -n 'HelloWorld', I assume Echo would be args[0], -n would be args[1] and HelloWorld would be args[2]

Comment: She calls **echo** not **Echo**